# Необновляющееся окно в браузере

Tags: jquery, html, php, javascript

Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться или как создать окно на сайте, которое не будет обновляться во время обновления  сайта. Независящее от сайта. Расскажите может, как сделать, код не нужен - просто в каком направлении мне двигаться. Большое спасибо

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду iframe ?

Comment: я не знаю что я имею ввиду поэтому и спрашиваю +)

Comment: IFrame или AJAX.

Comment: а AJAX ту тпри чем?

Comment: ...которое не будет обновлятся, когда юзер нажимает CTRL-R?

Comment: А, вы хотите, что бы при обновлении сайта окно не обновлялось? Тогда действительно только отдельное окно/вкладка.

Comment: да конечно!

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете в виду Окна Браузера:

```
var newwindow;
newwindow=window.open("адрес","заголовок","width=250,height=250");
```

также можно дополнительные параметры и управлять окном например:

```
newwindow.close();
```

это окно независимо от страницы открывшей его

Answer (score 0):

Человек имеет ввиду что вот сайт и на нем есть окошко - к примеру блок div с неким контентом справа в верхнем углу. Если пользователь нажимает ссылку "Блог", к примеру, то они переходит в раздел "Блог", но при этом окошко в верхнем правом углу не обновляется.

Я бы не марочался, а сделал это окно на всех страницах

Comment: Похоже, ТС имеет в виду не это. Ему надо не чтобы при обновлении части не обновлялся весь сайт, а чтобы при обновлении всего сайта не обновлялась часть.

Comment: Я присерно об этом же. Но только где это можно использовать?

Comment: много где, к примеру человек решил, что желает видеть переписку с человеком, а хочется ему видеть это окошко постоянно не обновляемым.